# Remotely check version of adobe reader installed

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, regedit

I need to find out the version of adobe reader installed on  5 or six remote servers. Looking for a batch file to find out the version of adobe installed where i will provide the hostname or ip address and the script will return the version of adobe installed on that machine.

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: i have not prepared any code. I just need a batch file to find the version of adobe reader on remote servers

Comment: Stackoverflow is a programmer's Q&A site; as such, it's for programming questions. You don't have a programming question but rather a request for a solution.

Comment: @AnindyaRoy - SO has been successful by sticking to a policy documented in https://stackoverflow.com/help See the part about creating a MCE (Minimal Complete Example). Questions with no code usually go to https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
$Servers = @('Server1','Server2','Server3')

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -Sciptblock {
  Get-WMIObject Win32_Product |
  Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'Adobe Acrobat Reader*'} |
  Select-Object Name, Version
}
```